# Calling WCF from IronPython does not return a complex type

Tags: wcf, ironpython

I'm calling a WCF Service function

```
[OperationContract]
ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo(); # ProcessInfo has a DataContract Attribute.
```

written in C# from a IronPython Script (v2.7).

The debugger proofs that the service is called and a correct object is returned.

But in the IPy script

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.ServiceModel')
import System.ServiceModel
clr.AddReference('Company.Service.Util')
from Company.Service.Util.Diagnostics import IServiceInspector 
bind = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
endpoint = System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:40099/ServiceInspector")
channel = System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory[IServiceInspector](bind, endpoint)
client = channel.CreateChannel()
pi = client.GetProcessInfo()
print "GetProcessInfo() returned:\n%s" % pi
```

None is received.

Both basicHttpBinding and tcpBinding have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the script with debug info: `ipy.exe -X:Debug -X:ExceptionDetail`

Try simplier service (e.g. return string) - I guess you might need to add reference to `System.Web` assembly where `ProcessInfo` is stored.

Comment: No exception is reported.
    `X:\lib>ipy -X:Debug -X:ExceptionDetail serviceInspector.ipy
    GetProcessInfo() returned:
    None`
ProcessInfo is a Company-defined class, not the System.Web.

Comment: No. I give up and will use a C# client. Thanks.

Comment: You can check my work with [IronPython and WCF](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/search/label/wcf).

Comment: Your TestClient.py was the starting point of my script ;-) But the WCF host to connect with is pure C# without an ipy wrapper.